# STM32 I2C BNO055 has big spikes in data in fused mode

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, arm, imu

I am reading euler angles in fused mode from BNO055 device. It gets correct angles, but there are big spikes from time to time, but only when the values are changing. I am sending data over USB to my python script then ploting it with matplotlib. You can see the result in this image below.

[image]

Previously I have calculated values from gyro and accelometter from 2 diffrent devices and there were no spikes on neihter of them. So the problem is with this device. In the image below there is a close up of the little spikes

[image]

When the spike happens, I see that the MSB is all ones:

[image]

I have seen there there could be a problem with I2C clock stretching, but I don't have an oscilator to test the signals.

I would greatly appreciate some help with this. If you need any aditional information please let me know. Here is the code for reading EUL angles:

[image]

Comment: pitch is -180~+180deg, and the range of roll is -90~+90deg, Bit 7 of UNIT_SEL_0x3B value =1, = the default setting =Android orientation. Did you set to 0?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I didn't change it.

Comment: Does the bn055 acknowledge the read request? If it’s ignoring you and you’re ignoring the ack then the bus will definitely return all ones. Apparently your read function should return HAL_OK if everything is hunky dory

Comment: Do you understand you are operating from Windows and need to change that register ( for reasons I dont understand) to 0?

Comment: I will try, but it is wierd because the code is run on stm32 which reads from bno055. So I don't understand why windows and android is even an option. -_(O.O)_-

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I tried setting the bit to 0 but the problem is still there. But thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: You ignore output status code from HAL_I2C_Meme_Read. Check it for error first. What I2C speed do you use? How many sensor are on the bus? How is the bus connected (wires? sensor on breadboard? pcb?)

Comment: @Misaz thank you for your feedback. I am currently using diffrent gyro and accelometer, but at a later time, I will comment here the data you are requesting.